# input function using user prompt

Tags: node.js, switch-statement, exceljs

I've posted this question before without success.

I have some lines making one user menu getting data from exceljs.

1 - How to put while condition inside this function, to get all rows to menu? Looks like switch(input) doesn't accept loop.

The logic is:
* Read costumers.xlsx to get all costumers.
* Loop all costumers as menu choices.
* After the choice it'll open another xlsx file with the name of chosen costumer
ie: 
1 - Costumer1
2 - Costumer2
If I chose 1 I'll open costumer1.xlsx

2 - How to take that choice and pass as string to open the xlsx?

```
wb_costumers.xlsx.readFile('costumers.xlsx').then(function(){
  sh_costumers = wb_costumers.getWorksheet("Sheet1");
  var ic = 2;

  while (ic <= sh_costumers.rowCount){
      console.log("Row " + sh_costumers.getRow(ic).getCell(1) + " - " + sh_costumers.getRow(ic).getCell(2)); 
      ic++; 
}
 });
function processChoice(input){
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var error = undefined;
    var func;

    switch(input){

        case sh_costumers.getRow(2).getCell(1).text :
            func = addPreset;               
        break;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some researches, I've found something about prompt (npm install prompt).

Now I can read my costumers configuration inside the xlsx file.

on workbook costumers.xlsx I have two columns:

cell1 = id
cell2 = costumer's name

on workbook check_(costumer's name).xlsx I have the informations what I want to place somewhere.

That's my code.

```
const prompt = require('prompt');
var Excel = require('exceljs');


var wb = new Excel.Workbook();
var wbc = new Excel.Workbook();



prompt.start();
var ic = 1;
wbc.xlsx.readFile('costumers.xlsx').then(function(){
  shc = wbc.getWorksheet("Sheet1");
  while (ic <= shc.rowCount){  
    console.log(shc.getRow(ic).getCell(1).value +" - "+ shc.getRow(ic).getCell(2).value);
    ic++;
  }

});


prompt.get(['costumer'], function (err, result) {
    if (err) { return onErr(err); }
    var costumer = shc.getRow(result.costumer).getCell(2).value;


    wb.xlsx.readFile('check_'+costumer+'.xlsx').then(function(){
      sh = wb.getWorksheet("Sheet1");
      console.log(sh.getRow(2).getCell(3).value);

    });

});

function onErr(err) {
    console.log(err);
    return 1;
}
```